# Book About Unknown Phenomena/Aliens/Bigfoot/Etc

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I have been haunted for years now about finding a book that was in my school library in the mid-to-late '80s. It was a compendium of various strange phenomena and had illustrations that went along with it.

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to track this thing down and during one such hunt today I found the book *Strange But True* by David Duncan. It is similar but I do no think it is the book I am looking for. To my best recollection, this book had a yellow cover. It was probably printed in the '70s or perhaps the '60s. Anyone out there know what this might be?

Comment: What legends were covered? Softcover? Hardcover? Illustrations? Photographs? Line drawings? Oil paintings? Was it just one region's legends or was it global?

Comment: I recommend going to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to find prompts to expand your question with details that will help us help you.

Comment: It had what I remember to be rather crude looking illustrations, which was part of the appeal. It was almost certainly soft cover. I remember there were various urban legends and some bigfoot stories and some alien-related stories.

Comment: Library books (especially 40-60 years ago) were often rebound for durability, so the color of the cover isn't necessarily much help in your search.

Comment: Did it have the title....the word "Phenomena!".....in multicolored spinning text on the front cover? I remember that exact book, and it sounds like you are describing, but it is being very elusive to find!

Comment: I really dont remember anything about the title. If you find out, please let me know!!!

Comment: Did it have a story about fish falling from the sky, and a story about supposed Aliens putting a Kentucky farm under siege? Was it a large book, almost 8.5x11 in size, softbound? I ran across a similar book at school in 4th grade, which would have been 1987 or 1988. What you are describing seems to be the same one.

Comment: I dont remember it being that large, but I think both of those stories were in there.

Comment: Did you ever remember what the book's title was? There were a couple answers below that were very close. I ordered them and read them both, but I dont think they were exactly the book Im looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (A) nonfiction books about cryptozoology, spiritualism, ufology and Forteana do not fall within the science fiction and fantasy genres, and (B) "book about paranormal stuff, yellow cover, read in the 80s" is not enough detail to identify a specific work.

Answer (score 3):

What the heck, I'll write an answer, I considered them "stories".

Possibly [*Strangely Enough!*](https://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2010/07/strangely-enough-cb-colby-scholastic.html) by C. B. Colby. I bought the abridged paperback version at a Scholastic book fair in the early 1970s.

There were interior illustrations...

[image]

and some of the hardback covers are at least yellow-ish.

[image]

[image]

(cover images from Amazon)

Comment: This could well be it! I just ordered a copy, so we'll see! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like one or another of the works of Charles Fort.  Published from 1909 through 1932, and collected together, reprinted in various bindings, and often quoted or plagiarized, these books led to the term "Fortean" to describe something too strange to be readily believed, even if reported as absolute truth.

Based on a quick search, it appears all five of his books (*The Outcast Manufacturers*, 1909, *The Book of the Damned*, 1919, *New Lands*, 1923, *Lo!*, 1931, and *Wild Talents*, 1932) may be still available, likely in ebook form.  It was common to find library-bound hard cover copies of these (especially *Lo!*) in libraries into the 1970s, at least in small towns where the library might not turn over its collection rapidly.

These would technically be off topic here, because they were published as non-fiction, but the subject matter makes them seem very much like SF/Fantasy.

Comment: Fort's books are available from Dover Publications in physical form. Except "Outcast", I never heard of that one.

Comment: Just looked into it. Its definitely not those but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but if you're still looking; I read, in about the same time period, a book called There Are Monsters In The Earth.  It covered all of the most famous cryptids, with the largest two sections being on Bigfoot and Nessie.  The book, as I recall, had a dark blue cover.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a listing for it anywhere online.  I believe the original printing was in 1978, at the height of the 70's Bigfoot fad (Six Million Dollar Man, In Search Of..., etc.).  I can tell you that it treated the subjects respectfully and Peter Byrne figured prominently.  Hope this might help.