# Looking for 1970s children's book of scary stories - person hung in their jail cell and placed a curse

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

In the late 1970s my sister had a children's book of scary/ghost stories. My memory is vague so some of the things I state may not be factual.

The book had a soft cover and included black and white illustrations for each story. It may have been a Scholastic book because that is where many of our books came from. The story I remember is about a person that was placed in a jail cell and hung themselves with  a sheet. I think the person placed a curse on the jail cell because people would die if they went inside. I remember an illustration showing the person hanging from the sheet which was tied to the window's metal bars.

Hopefully someone will remember this story and the book.

Thanks,
Marvin

**Update:** I found the illustrations and a reference to the story here: https://www.scaryforkids.com/crazy-mary/
I was wrong about the illustration being black and white. The creator of the post does not cite the book where the story originated. Perhaps someone will recognize the story and illustration? [image: hanging]

Comment: Possibly this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227713/28516